# Add partition to dynamic disk with 4 partitions already?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

I'm thinking about dual-booting Win 8.1 and Xubuntu, but I have encountered a problem. I have 4 partitions already on my HP Laptop, laid out like so:

```
+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| Volume        | Layout | Type    | File System | Status                                |
|---------------+--------+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------|
| (F:)          | Simple | Dynamic | NTFS        | Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump) |
| HP_TOOLS (E:) | Simple | Dynamic | FAT32       | Healthy (Primary Partition)           |
| Recovery (D:) | Simple | Dynamic | NTFS        | Healthy (Primary Partition)           |
| SYSTEM        | Simple | Dynamic | NTFS        | Healthy (System)                      |
+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
```

To make matters worse, my computer does not have a GPT partition table and uses BIOS instead of UEFI, so GPT is out of the question. I should note that I once shrunk my main partition (F:) when I thought about dual-booting once but then expanded back into the unallocated space when I 'chickened out'. This converted my disk to a Dynamic type.

I also noticed that under Status for my F: partition it is not listed as Primary. Did I accidentally convert it to an extended partition when I partitioned before?

I don't want to delete or convert any partitions. Am I outta' luck or can I create a fifth partition?

Comment: Windows not being able to boot in a BIOS/GPT combination is an artificial restriction. [See here](http://superuser.com/a/375788/219095). Since you converted to dynamic disks, you should already be able to create up to 2000 partitions.

Comment: @DanielB, can you install Xubuntu 14.10 to a dynamic disk?